# Django: ImportError: cannot import name receiver

Tags: python, django

Very basic django app that gives me the following when I try to do anything (runserver, syncdb). Thoughts?

If it is a problem with one of my files, could you help guide me as to what the issue may be?

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.dispatch.dispatcher import Signal, receiver
ImportError: cannot import name receiver
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with Django-1.3 beta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883802/problem-with-django-1-3-beta) - disregard the version number; in general this error occurs when you installed multiple versions of Django.

Comment: How can I uninstall the other djangos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[receiver should be imported from the dispatch module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/):

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
```

Note that the receiver decorator was added in only in Django 1.3. You can check your django version by:

```
import django
django.VERSION
```

edit:

The wrong import statement is part of the `__init__` module of the dispatch package itself, which can have gotten there by a version re-write. Delete the whole django package directory (..C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django) and re-install. It is a crude, but probably the best solution.

Comment: but it was working earlier and I have ne included that statement. Why now?

Comment: If I'm on a Mac, where would Django be located?

Comment: my guess based on [here](http://docs.python.org/using/mac.html) is /usr/bin/python/Lib/site-packages/django