# Django Import Error. Cannot import name reciever

Tags: python, django, importerror

I'm learning django and while trying to use Signal and receiver, I receive an ImportError.
Code:

```py
from django.dispatch import reciever
```

Error:

```py
  File "C:\Users\krish\Documents\python\django_project\users\signals.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.dispatch import reciever
ImportError: cannot import name 'reciever' from 'django.dispatch' (C:\Users\krish\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\__init__.py)
```

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700154/django-importerror-cannot-import-name-receiver) and I tried deleting and re-adding the django module(s) but nothing happened. What can I do to fix this and make it work?

I'm using django-2.3 and python 3.7.3

Comment: Please share your code where you try to import, otherwise we can't see where the problem is.

Comment: That error message specifically refers to `/Library/Python/2.7/`.  I don't think you are using Python 3.7.3.

Comment: @RobKwasowski Yes, sorry.

Comment: @JohnGordon Hmm. Oops, I had copied the wrong error message. Changed it

Comment: Did you spell "reciever" wrong ? shouldn't it be receiver? i before except after c?

Comment: @JoeA FACEPALM. OMG, how did I not notice that.

Comment: It's all good no worries just be careful of spelling errors it happens to me all the time.The traceback is helpful

Comment: @JoeA I've always spelled receiver like 'reciever'. It always made more sense to me.... Ugh

Comment: @12944qwerty I know It sounds close to that when you sound it out. Don't sweat it man it happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user misspelled the import statement it happens to everyone. The user had:

```
 from django.dispatch import reciever
```

meanwhile it should be:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
```

The golden rule: i before e except after c